# Dockerfile: How to incorporate shell command on image's startup, every time?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I want to add some update commands to my linux docker file. I do not have the ability to attach a script; just to alter its dockerfile.

How can I translate this command:

```
apt update -y && apt full-upgrade -y && apt autoremove -y && apt clean -y && apt autoclean -y
```

Into something docker will take and use, on start-up?

This is not working:

```
CMD ["run", "apt", "update", "-y", "&&", "apt", "full-upgrade", "-y", && "apt", "autoremove", "-y", "&&", "apt", "clean", "-y", "&&", "apt", "autoclean", "-y"]
```

Comment: I heavily advice against this. This should be done at image build time, not container start time.

Comment: What if the image is not being kept up-to-date as fast as I would need it?

Comment: Make it your own image, update it yourself. Do it in a container that is based on whatever file you are using.

Comment: It is also generally regarded as best practice to have reproducible builds. Having something like `apt update && apt (full-)upgrade` is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I agree with all the comments that the specific script you want to run at startup is a bad idea. However, the *general* solution to your question is quite common. If we want some shell commands to execute whenever a container starts, we can set up an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) script.

An `ENTRYPOINT` script runs when the container starts.  It receives as arguments the value of the `CMD` setting in your Dockerfile. It can do anything with those arguments, including ignoring them, passing them as arguments to some other command, or simply executing them directly -- either before or after performing other actions.  For example, if have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM docker.io/ubuntu:22.04

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

And `docker-entrypoint.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade

exec "$@"
```

Then whenver the container starts it will first run those two `apt-get` commands, and it will then run whatever was passed as the `CMD`.  By default, we get a shell:

```
host$ docker run --rm -it myimage
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [927 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [449 kB]
...lots of text from apt...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
root@8f1adcd0d2d0:/#
```

Those same `apt` commands will run even if we pass in  a command on the `docker run` command line:

```
host$ docker run --rm -it myimage date
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [927 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [449 kB]
...lots of text from apt...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Tue Jun  6 05:50:50 PM EDT 2023
host$
```

---

Some images already include an `ENTRYPOINT` script, in which case this solution isn't appropriate (because it would **replace** the existing `ENTRYPOINT` script). In some cases, the pre-existing `ENTRYPOINT` script may already provide an extension mechanism allowing you to pass in arbitrary scripts to execute at runtime (the [`postgres`](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) image is a good example of this); in other cases, you would have to explicitly execute the original `ENTRYPOINT` script from your replacement in order to both implement your new logic and preserve the existing functionality of the image.

Comment: The full explanation is truly helpful!